# SQLCipher runs successfully with simulator but doesnt build

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql, sqlite, sqlcipher

SQLCipher runs successfully with simulator but doesnt build with device; instead I get the following errors:

> cp: libssl.a: No such file or directory

and

> sqlite3.c:91838: internal compiler error: in find_src_set_src, at var-tracking.c:1922

I have followed the entire procedure given at SQLCIPHER website. And it runs successfully on simulator but when i change it to iOSDevice the above errors appears.
Kindly help me asap

Comment: what device architecture are you building for?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using the official 2.0 release from this repository, https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher, It addresses an issue building for armv6.

Answer (score 0):

Open openssl.xcodeproj and follow instructions form this site:
http://programmer-in-paradise.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-build-openssl-in-xcode.html
You need to setup a new target then bring libssl.a in your project.

If you still have problems:
As XCode 4.3(2) complains in release and test on device  (not in simulator) about arm 6, better is to compile your own openssl libraries [see http://www.x2on.de/2010/07/13/tutorial-iphone-app-with-compiled-openssl-1-0-0a-library/]. You just need to adjust some paths [like /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs, if you're familiar with scripting]. I managed to build libs for last version of OpenSSL [2012 openssl-1.0.1c], then include in my project and able to build release and archive for distribution, with encrypted db.